# Take N elements with saving that satisfies predicate

Tags: rust

I have that vec of strings

```rust
vec![
    "import a\n",
    "\n",
    "\n",
    "b = 1 + 2\n",
    "\n",
    "print(b)\n",
    "print(b + 1)\n",
    "\n"
];
```

And I want to take first 3 non `"\n"` lines also saving all `"\n"` lines between them. So that result would be this

```rust
vec![
    "import a\n",
    "\n",
    "\n",
    "b = 1 + 2\n",
    "\n",
    "print(b)\n"
];
```

Ideally if it could be done like this

```rust
lines.take_n_saving(3, |line| line == "\n")
```

Comment: loop the vector and maintain a counter to count the non "\n" lines and stop the loop if it exceeds the counter limit

Comment: @Mutex thanks for the solution idea. But can it be done like in my example (I just added preferred solution), so that I don't need extra variable?

Comment: well I wish I could help you but I'm also still a rust beginner :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::iter::filter`. Below is an example:

```
fn take_n_saving<'a, F: Fn(&str) -> bool>(n: i32, input: Vec<&'a str>, f: F)
    -> Vec<&'a str>
{
    let mut count = 0;

    return input
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|x| match count >= n {
            true => false,
            false => {
                if !f(x) {
                    count += 1;
                }
                true
            }
        })
        .collect();
}
fn main() {
    let input = vec![
        "import a\n",
        "\n",
        "\n",
        "b = 1 + 2\n",
        "\n",
        "print(b)\n",
        "print(b + 1)\n",
        "\n",
    ];

    let output: Vec<_> = take_n_saving(3, input, |x: &str| x == "\n");

    println!("{:?}", output);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Vec::retain()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) can do this in-place, but you need an external counter (captured by the closure).

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut lines = vec![
        "import a\n",
        "\n",
        "\n",
        "b = 1 + 2\n",
        "\n",
        "print(b)\n",
        "print(b + 1)\n",
        "\n",
    ];
    let mut keep = 3;
    lines.retain(|l| {
        let result = keep > 0;
        if *l != "\n" {
            keep -= 1;
        }
        result
    });
    println!("{:?}", lines);
}
/*
["import a\n", "\n", "\n", "b = 1 + 2\n", "\n", "print(b)\n"]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I just search through rust source code and found that `.take()` [uses](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a804c4b1123ae665a8d4f726524109c49efac5b6/library/core/src/iter/adapters/take.rs#L27-L41) `Take` under the hood. I think that this `Take` can be subclassed from something like `TakePred`

```rust
impl<I> Iterator for TakePred<I> where I: Iterator {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<<I as Iterator>::Item> {
        if self.n != 0 {
            let elem = self.iter.next()
            if !self.pred(elem) {
                self.n -= 1
            }
            elem
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

So that solution for my problem would be this

```rust
lines.take_pred(3, |line| line == "\n")
```

And `Take` implementation would be this (pseudo)

```rust
Take(n) = TakePred(n, pred: always())
```

But it is just an idea, not an exact solution.